# Aggregate over time every minute with duplicates

Tags: r

It's been a couple of days I'm facing some difficulties in trying to count repeated observations in a certain period of time, let's say every minutes.
I basically need to count the number of person inside a certain area every minute, the ID is detected because the host is connected to my Wi-Fi network.
Practically, I've something like this:

```
ID           DATE

247  2017-03-20 15:57
247  2017-03-20 16:01
247  2017-03-20 16:01
247  2017-03-20 16:02
201  2017-03-20 16:02
278  2017-03-20 16:02
247  2017-03-20 16:03
201  2017-03-20 16:03
278  2017-03-20 16:10
278  2017-03-20 16:10
278  2017-03-20 16:10
281  2017-03-20 16:30
```

I need a code that returns the number of ID every minute, considering duplicates, so the result should look like this:

```
         DATE          ID present

  2017-03-20 16:01         1
  2017-03-20 16:02         3
  2017-03-20 16:03         2
  2017-03-20 16:10         1
  2017-03-20 16:30         1
```

Is there a way to customize such code to gave the same result hourly, daily and monthly?
The best code I found is this one:

```
output <- aggregate(data$mac ~ cut(data$date, "1 min"), data, count)
```

it returns:

```
     DATE          ID present

  2017-03-20 16:01         1
  2017-03-20 16:02   1, 2, 3
  2017-03-20 16:03      1, 2
  2017-03-20 16:10         1
  2017-03-20 16:30         1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)

df[!duplicated(df),] %>% 
       group_by(DATE) %>% 
       summarise(new = n())

# A tibble: 6 × 2
#                 DATE   new
#               <dttm> <int>
#1 2017-03-20 15:57:00     1
#2 2017-03-20 16:01:00     1
#3 2017-03-20 16:02:00     3
#4 2017-03-20 16:03:00     2
#5 2017-03-20 16:10:00     1
#6 2017-03-20 16:30:00     1
```

To do this via Base R then,

```
aggregate(ID ~ DATE, df[!duplicated(df),], FUN = length)

                 DATE ID
#1 2017-03-20 15:57:00  1
#2 2017-03-20 16:01:00  1
#3 2017-03-20 16:02:00  3
#4 2017-03-20 16:03:00  2
#5 2017-03-20 16:10:00  1
#6 2017-03-20 16:30:00  1
```

Comment: it says i can't use dplyr cuz I have R 3.1.1

Comment: Edited but you should really update. We are at version 3.3.2 now!

Comment: alternatives?
I'm on debian, latest versions are not available

Comment: thanks man, what if i need to change the time range of the analysis, and obtain the same result? for example, every hour